# ¿Es "hacer la higa" una expresión común en España? ¿Qué significa exactamente?

Tags: expresiones, significado, españa

Acabo de terminar de leerme la novela *[Ready player one](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ready_Player_One)*, de Ernest Cline. No diré nada sobre la novela en sí porque no es el sitio, pero sí me gustaría hacer un par comentarios sobre la traducción (al español de España). Básicamente no hay gran cosa que reprochar, habida cuenta de que no he leído la versión original, aunque sí ha habido un par de expresiones que me han sonado raras:

- La primera es "explicar un chiste". No es la primera vez que la oigo, ya en la traducción de *[Porco Rosso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porco_Rosso)* dicen "explícame una historia". La tengo como un catalanismo, dado que muchas traducciones se hacen allí y contienen expresiones que no se usan en el resto del país. Para mí los chistes, los cuentos y las historias se cuentan, no se explican. Bueno, los chistes se explican cuando el que los oye no los entiende de primeras, pero no se explican de partida. Por tanto esa expresión me suena muy rara.
- La segunda, la que nos ocupa, es "hacer la higa". Aparece (creo) hasta en tres ocasiones durante el libro. No la había oído jamás en la vida.

Según el diccionario, una ***[higa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KNCKZAT)*** es un "gesto que se ejecuta con la mano, cerrado el puño, mostrando el dedo pulgar por entre el dedo índice y el cordial, con el que se señalaba a las personas infames o se hacía desprecio de ellas". También puede ser sencillamente una "burla o desprecio".

Ignoro con qué sentido se usa en el libro, pero al no haber oído la expresión nunca me suena rarísima. Dejando aparte el motivo por el que el traductor pudo elegirla como traducción del original, ¿es de uso habitual en alguna parte de España? Si es así, ¿se usa con alguno de los sentidos mencionados por la RAE? ¿O se usa actualmente con algún otro sentido más reciente?

Ejemplo de traducción:

> *He gave me the finger; then his avatar disappeared as he logged out of the chat room.*
>   Volvió a hacerme la higa y su avatar desapareció cuando se desconectó de la sala de chat.

Comment: Perdón, se me olvidaba, sí que hay una cosa más de la traducción digna de mención: el traducir el término _mecha_ (referido a los robots gigantes del anime japonés) como _mecano_.

Answer (score 5):

No me había fijado en esas expresiones cuando leí el libro.

1.- Cuando se utiliza la expresión "explicando chistes",  por el contexto creo que tanto podría ser "contar chistes", como  "explicarlos". Seguramente sea "contar chistes", pero habría  que leer la versión original, a ver qué dice. (No sé cómo se dirá en catalán). El párrafo dice:

"Finalmente se volvió y me dedicó una sonrisa, y yo la reconocí al momento: era el mismo rictus de gato de Cheshire que había visto miles de veces dibujado en el rostro del avatar de Hache, durante las incontables noches que habíamos pasado juntos en Oasis, explicándonos chistes malos y viendo películas baratas."

2.- Hacer la Higa no es una expresión habitual, al menos en mi entorno. Sin embargo, normalmente la asocio con el significado que le da el DLE en el enlace que pusiste, más abajo, a la expresión *dar, o hacer (a alguien) una higa*. Que es *contra el aojo*. Es decir, es un gesto para ahuyentar el mal de ojo. También hay amuletos con forma de higa, para eso mismo.

Desconozco cómo se usa la expresión en Cataluña o en catalán. Pero es verdad que queda un poco raro su uso en el libro. No me imagino a un chaval estadounidense haciendo la higa como insulto (cerrar el puño sacando el dedo gordo entre el índice y el cordial). Aunque según el DLE es un uso adecuado, yo al leer me lo imagino como *hacer la peineta* pero se refiere a un gesto diferente: cerrar el puño y sacar el dedo medio.

En la entrada de la Wikipedia para *higa* se refiere a este segundo gesto. Desconozco si ambos gestos son llamados igual en la actualidad, o si lo son en unas zonas y no en otras.

Comment: Ciertamente, yo también lo entendía como "hacer la peineta" o "la peseta". Por eso me extrañó. Y sobre lo de los chistes malos, yo entiendo que los contaban y no que los explicaban. Gracias por tu respuesta, ¡y bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]!

Answer (score 4):

**Covarrubias** recoge:

> "HIGA es una manera de menosprecio que hazemos cerrando el puño, y mostrando el dedo pulgar por entre el dedo indice, y el medio, es disfraçada pulla. La higa antigua era tan solamente vna semejanza del miembro viril, estendido el dedo medio, y encogiendo el indize, y el auricular: y assi se dezia media vnguem oftendere...
>
> Dize vn prouerbio, Mee yo claro y vna higa para el medico; dixolo Marcial....
>
> Tambiem es cosa vsada al que ha parecido bien darle vna higa, diziendo, Toma porque no os aojen...."

En el **Quijote** aparece varias veces, siempre con el sentido de menosprecio, no contra el aojo. Por ejemplo, en el Capítulo XXXII, comparando (favorablemente) a Héctor, Aquiles y Roldán con el Gran Capitán y con Diego García, el ventero dice:

> ¡Dos higas para el Gran Capitán y para ese Diego García que dice!

o en el Capítulo LXV, Sancho consuela a Don Quijote:

> ... dé una higa al médico, pues no le ha menester para que le cure en esta enfermedad ...

La expresión solo la he escuchado un par de veces, por lo que dudo que sea de uso habitual.

En cuanto a "explicar un chiste", coincido con las otras respuestas.

Comment: Resulta curioso que en 1611 Covarrubias diga que el gesto que hoy conocemos como la peseta o peineta era por entonces una "higa antigua". Igual el gesto era demasiado obsceno para el siglo XVII y se cambió por la versión "disfrazada", más sutil. Gracias por tu respuesta, ¡y bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]!

Answer (score 1):

Desde Alicante (España), puedo decir que

1. "Explicar un chiste" sólo lo conocía como exponer el chiste de forma clara para que se entienda la causa de su gracia, nunca como la simple exposición.
2. Nunca había escuchado la expresión "hacer la higa".

Answer (score 0):

En Colombia, esa expresión la conozco como «mamola» y si significa también menosprecio, pues, es para insultar. Se hace con el dedo gordo entre el índice y el corazón y levantándolo hacía la otra persona, como cuando se hace una pistola (mostrando el corazón y el pulgar).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/25776)

Comment: Por favor, pongan esto como **comentario** a la pregunta